# Tables combination in Power Query

Tags: excel, datatables, powerquery

Hello everyone and thanks in advance to those will take the time to read and possibly help.
I'm sure my question is pretty "dumb", but anyway I'm just moving my first steps with Pwer Query, so here's my problem.

I have a folder with many tables (in separate files), all of them have the very same structure, as follow:

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is to combine ALL the tables from that folder (and the number of files will keep increasing), knowing that the column "m" is always the same for all tables (it contains values from 0 to 100 with increases of 0.05). So, I'd like to have:

Column "m" and column "tm" from the first table, followed by all the "tm" columns all the other files (tables), with the header name to be replaced by the file name (as said "m" colums are always the same).

I'd like this operation to be performed automatically with PowerQuery, so that every time I add a file (which contains the table, always with the same name), the big table is updated. This table is structured like this:

[image]

(note that I will have some #N/A and that's ok for me - provided that it's not "disturbing" Power Query. Keeping it will help me when producing charts)

Any idea from your side?

Thanks a lot,

Cris

Comment: Did you try something? You could share your attempt... In general, if you go to `Get Data -> From Folder` from there it could be pretty self-explanatory. If not, come back with your attempt.

Comment: I did try, but I can't get what I want. I can't find a way to add columns to the first table. As I said, I am learning...

Comment: .xlsx or .csv's?

Comment: They are all .xlsx

Comment: [This, from Microsoft,](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4) might help.

Comment: I had found that Microsoft page and followed instructions. It's not doing what I need, unfortuntaley...

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. Paste into home...advanced editor ...  and edit first row to reflect your actual file path

Reads in all .xlsx from specified directory, combines their tables, then does a pivot on tm

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory\"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Remove filename extension" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{{"Name", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_,".xlsx")}}),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Remove filename extension",{"Name", "Data"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Other Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Data", List,List),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Data", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Data"[Name]), "Name", "tm", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: did this work for you?